# Execute query in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This very simple query I am trying to execute in SQL Server Management Studio. But it gives error:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '`'.

I also tried by replacing  `with`'` but still no help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backtick (`` ` ``) character is only used for MySql. It's not standard. Sql Server is a completely different animal. You need to use square-brackets (`[` and `]` -- also not standard) to enclose table and column names with Sql Server. Sql Server also supports double quotes (`"`), which are part of the SQL Standard, but for some reason less-common.

While I'm at it, the ENGINE and AUTO_INCREMENT, and CHARSET clauses are also MySql-specific.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id int IDENTITY(25,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [name] varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  "address" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  telephone varchar(45) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: I am facing this issue with above query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837519/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-identity-column

Comment: You have the seed and increment backwards

Answer (score 1):

in tsql

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id int identity(0,25) NOT NULL,
  name nvarchar(45) NOT NULL,
  email nvarchar(45) NOT NULL,
  address nvarchar(45) NOT NULL,
  telephone nvarchar(45) NOT NULL

  CONSTRAINT contact_PK PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
)
```

You can't specify engine.

identity(0,25) means initial value = 0, increment = 25

You don't specify character set for the table, you can declare individual columns as varchar or nvcarchar -- the n stands for unicode. You can also specify a collation sequence for each column.

If you want a column name that is irregular (keyword, embedded space, etc.)  you quote the column name as [column name] -- don't use irregular column names if you have a choice, it just makes things a pain to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id[int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  telephone varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
)
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: It still won't like `ENGINE=InnoDB`, `AUTO_INCREMENT=25`, or `CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: @Krupa: thanks, but just need to remove last line in your answer. Joel corrected it

Comment: @Krupa: can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837519/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-identity-column